# Fixar posição das RelativeLayout na Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Boa tarde.

Quero fixar a posição de dois `RelativeLayout` na tela, porém quando o usuário altera o texto do `TextSwitcher` o `RelativeLayout` a que ele pertence aumenta de tamanho, e assim o botão Pular está se mexendo para cima e para baixo e gostaria de deixar ele no mesmo lugar. Como posso arrumar para resolver este problema?

Segue o XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="br.com.emergencyonline.Introduction" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/introduction_emergency_online"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rlDescriptions"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:background="@color/button_material_light">

<TextSwitcher 
    android:id="@+id/tsIntroduction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rlPular"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/background_material_dark">

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnPular"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/jump" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: O problema nesse caso é que você deixou o `TextSwitcher` ter o seu tamanho variável, e com alterações que você faz, ele faz flutuar quem estiver abaixo dele. Uma possível solução seria limitar o tamanho dele para o maior possível. Ou mudar a posição do botão.

Comment: Era isso mesmo @Wakim, obrigado.